# Curved movement from a Vector2 position to an other

Tags: c#, xna, move, curve

Currently, to move a fly from position to position, I'm using this :

```
    DirectionNormalized = (positionTarget - position).Normalize;
```

and

```
    position += DirectionNormalized *
            vitesseP2P *
            (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

So, the fly flies (joke : done) in a line from A point to B point to C point to D point etc.

But I would like to curve its trajectory.
It's incredible, I thought it was easy but I'm stuck for hours.

hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way to achieve this is by using a Bezier curve.  The Bezier algorithm takes a set of points - two end points and a number of control points - and produces a series of points at various positions along the curve defined by those points.

The generalized form of the Bezier algorithm is an iterative reduction, but we can unroll it for the specific 4-point case and generate a `BezierInterpolate` function like this:

```
public static Vector2 BezierInterpolate(Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 c0, Vector2 c1, float fraction)
{
    // first stage, linear interpolate point pairs: [p0, c0], [c0, c1], [c1, p1]
    Vector2 p0c0 = Vector2.Lerp(p0, c0, fraction);
    Vector2 c0c1 = Vector2.Lerp(c0, c1, fraction);
    Vector2 c1p1 = Vector2.Lerp(c1, p1, fraction);

    // second stage, reduce to two points
    Vector2 l = Vector2.Lerp(p0c0, c0c1, fraction);
    Vector2 r = Vector2.Lerp(c0c1, c1p1, fraction);

    // final stage, reduce to result point and return
    return Vector2.Lerp(l, r, fraction);
}
```

This will give you the position of a point that is a certain fraction along the curve.  If you have a start and finish time of your animation for instance, you can generate the current position of your fly using the above.

First though, you need to define the control points.  I'd use something like this:

```
static System.Random prng = new System.Random();

public static Vector2 genControlPoint(Vector2 l, Vector2 r)
{
    // get a random angle between +/-(15..90) degrees off line
    float angle = (float)((((prng.NextDouble() * 5) + 1) / 12) * Math.PI * (prng.Next(0, 2) * 2 - 1));

    // create rotation matrix
    Matrix rot = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle);

    // get point offset half-way between two points
    Vector2 ofs = Vector2.op_Multiply(Vector2.op_Subtract(l, r), 0.5);

    // apply rotation
    ofs = Vector2.Transform(ofs, rot);

    // return point as control
    return Vector2.op_Add(l, ofs);
}

....

Vector2 p0 = FlyStartPoint();
Vector2 p1 = FlyEndPoint();
// generate randomized control points for flight path
Vector2 c0 = genControlPoint(p0, p1);
Vector2 c1 = genControlPoint(p1, p0);
```

At this point you have a set of four points suitable for passing as the first 4 parameters to the BezierInterpolate method, from which you can determine the position of the 'fly' at a specific time.

Bezier curves start out scary, but once you understand them they are useful tools.  Doing it by hand as I do here gives you a bit more understanding of what is actually going on in the background when you call `Vector2.Hermite` or `Vector2.CatmullRom`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the built-in methods. When you just need to quickly make something move smoothly - these are the way to go.

Comment: I don't generally use XNA, so I have my own vector class.  If I ever do use XNA, I suspect I'm going to be writing a lot of extension methods.  Rotation matrices are all well and good, but it's simpler to do the math by hand than use `matrix = Matrix.CreateXXX(); Vector2.Transform(matrix);`  I know, they're optimized.  But still... `x + y` beats `Vector2.op_Add(x, y)` any day :P

Comment: @Corey Thx for your answer, but I still think that's a bit more complicated than it should be. When the fly reachs the 1st point, I should calculate the new normalized vector (and keep in memory the previous one), if I modify smoothly the previous one to the new one, the fly will move in curve. I think. I'll keep your answer in mind. (If you have an idea to modify a normalized `Vector2`...) Thx for participed.

Comment: @Sharpnel Glad I could help.  Once you understand this part, general curve construction gets a bit easier.  The XNA `Curve` class is definitely worth a look, but understanding how Bezier interpolation works is A Good Thing :P

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a spline and position (over time) along that spline.

See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/apundit/DrawingCurves11182005012515AM/DrawingCurves.aspx

An alternative approach is to use a physics engine. You could give your fly a mass and velocity, and apply changes in motion by altering it's velocity.

Comment: I don't want to use a physic engine for this little fly, it's just a little animation to make the game more _Alive_. Do you have a sample or pseudo-code to calculate a spline ? I don't know what it is :x

Comment: Link added. Best if you learn splines before using them though.

Comment: I don't think it's very appropriate. I'll read deeper but I think I just have to modify the normalized `Vector2`. thx for participated

Answer (score 0):

The Xna framework has a built in Curve class to do just this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.curve.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.curve(v=XNAGameStudio.35).aspx

A sample with code is found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203908.aspx

They even created a special curve editor to easily slap your curve into your code:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/curve_editor